# React-Quill with Formik is not updating props

Tags: reactjs, formik, react-quill

I am using `Formik` and `React-Quill` in my form,

The value seems to be updating when i use `<input>` but when i plug-in `<ReactQuill />` it's not.

Is there something wrong with the setup?

```
<Field
    name="designation"
    value={this.props.values.designation}
    render={({ field /* _form */ }) => (
        // <input {...field} placeholder="designation" />
        <ReactQuill
            {...field}
        />
    )}
/>
```

Answer (score 3):

For anybody who is still interested in the answer (like I was), you can find it [here](https://github.com/jaredpalmer/formik/issues/1383#issuecomment-493934980):

```
<Formik initialValues={{ designation: '' }}>
    <Field name="designation">
        {({ field }) => <ReactQuill value={field.value} onChange={field.onChange(field.name)} />}
    </Field>
</Formik>
```

This helps match formik `field` to ReactQuill props.

Answer (score 2):

I am using "setFieldValue" to update changes. This is working perfectly fine for dynamic Formik forms.

```
<ReactQuill 
value={values.description}
onChange={v => setFieldValue('description', v)} 
/>
```